# doubleclick on a datagridview preluate dates from selected raws

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two forms:
In first a listview. On double click on a raw, the values from the row transfer to texboxes in the second form. The code is nextone:

```
    public void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        int index = listView1.FocusedItem.Index;

        Form2 newForm = new Form2();
        newForm.H_id = listView1.Items[index].Text;
        newForm.Serie = listView1.Items[index].SubItems[1].Text;
        newForm.Numar = listView1.Items[index].SubItems[2].Text;
        newForm.Partener = listView1.Items[index].SubItems[3].Text;
        newForm.Data = Convert.ToDateTime(listView1.Items[index].SubItems[4].Text);         
        newForm.Show();
```

I want to do the same but with a datagridview. How i do?

Answer (score 0):

Hope help you :D

```
private void dataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
        int index = e.RowIndex;

        Form2 newForm = new Form2();
        newForm.H_id = dataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value;
        newForm.Serie = dataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value;
        newForm.Numar = dataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value;
        newForm.Partener = dataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value;
        newForm.Data = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value);         
        newForm.Show();
        }
```

Comment: I have done what u wrote but i have the next error:Error 1 No overload for 'dataGridView1_DoubleClick' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler' C:\Users\alexandru.giura\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Alex ERP\Alex ERP\Form1.Designer.cs 271 47 Alex ERP

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CellDoubleClick event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.celldoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx). If you want to select full row set SelectionMode property to to DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect.